# php JSON encode float number

Tags: php, json, floating-point

it seems a simple thing: I would like to encode:

```
echo json_encode(array('lol' => 104564563225.1));
```

gives:

```
{"lol":1.0e+11}
```

I would like to be the output:

```
{"lol":104564563225.1}
```

How can this be achieved?
some more server data just in case:

```
PHP Version 5.6.0
System  Windows NT XXXXXXXXXXXXXX 6.3 build 9200 (Windows Server 2012 R2
Standard Edition) i586
Build Date  Aug 27 2014 11:49:46
Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-   build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" 
"--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php.ini
```

Comment: echo json_encode(array('lol' => 104564563225.1)); output is **{"lol":104564563225.1}** with PHP Version 5.6.4 maybe google for a bug in your version or on your build

Comment: I will update the PHP version and check it again. http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: I managed it by uninstalling php versions installed by MS Web Platform Installer stop the server and reinstall it again. Now it is working fine. Thanks! Using the WPI the most recent version of Php is 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string representation of floating point numbers depends on the [`precision`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) configuration (see its documentation on [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) directives).

Also, `echo(104564563225.1);` should display the same value as `json_encode()` produces.

By default the `precision` is `14` and with this value your code displays:

```
{"lol":104564563225.1}
```

Maybe it has a lower value on your system.

You can get its current value from your script using [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php):

```
echo(ini_get('precision'));
```

and you can change it using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('precision', '14');
```

Of course, searching and changing it in your `php.ini` is another option, if it's available to you.